# Non-binary(hex) characters in string received over TCP with Python

Tags: python, networking, character, bit

maybe this is a noob question, but I'm receiving some data over TCP and when I look at the string I get the following:

`\x00\r\xeb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01t\x00`

What is that `\r` character, and what does the `t` in `\x01t` mean?

I've tried Googling, but I'm not sure what to Google for...

thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look much like any encoding I can think of (four NULL bytes in a row?). Looks more like binary data, I'd say...

Comment: It is a response I get from a traffic simulator with a TCP server, and I have to parse it myself based on the length(1st byte) and the command(2nd byte), so how do I interpret the `r` and the `t`?

Comment: In hex, this is `00 0d eb 00 00 00 00 01 74 00`. `\r`, carriage return, is the same as 0x0d and the letter t corresponds to 0x74.

Comment: -1: Don't ask us.  Who is sending the data?  Ask them.  They actually know what data they're sending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viewing binary data in strings can sometimes be confusing, especially if they're long, but you can always convert it to some easier-to-read hex.

```
>>> data = '\x00\r\xeb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01t\x00'
>>> ' '.join(["%02X" % ord(char) for char in data])
'00 0D EB 00 00 00 00 01 74 00'
```

---

Also, if you're just parsing the byte string into fields, just ignore the string and just go right to unpacking it with the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> length, command, eggs, spam = struct.unpack('!BBi4s',data)
>>> #...whatever your fields really are
>>> print "len: %i\ncmd: %i\negg qty: %i\nspam flavor: '%s'" % (
...     length, command, eggs, spam)
len: 0
cmd: 13
egg qty: -352321536
spam flavor: ' ☺t '
```

Answer (score 9):

`\r` is a carriage return (0x0d), the `t` is a `t`.

Comment: If that's the case, why isn't it given simply as 0x0d?

Comment: Because there's a standard escape, `\r`, designated for it.  Search for "C character escapes" and you'll find a table of how they're represented.

Comment: @nieldw Python represents `bytes` objects as strings of hex values identifying each byte, except when the hex value is that of a printable/commonly used ASCII value.

Answer (score 2):

When displaying data as a string, printable characters (such as 't' are displayed as characters, known control sequences are displayed as escapes, and other bytes are displayed in \x## form.  Example:

```
>>> s='\x74\x0d\x99'
>>> s
't\r\x99'
```

You can dump a hexadecimal form with:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(s)
'740d99'
```